# When to seperate condition/logic between controller and view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I notice that I have some simple logic and conditions (if...else) all over my view, instead of controller. They aren't necessarily complex conditions because they just output different text based on the output.

I just don't know how to determine when to put in the controller, when not to put in the controller. Is there any performance issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some logic in the view is not bad per se, as long as you have the roles of the controller (what to do and what to show) and view (how to show) separated. This helps you have understandable and maintainable code. A side note: models are where all the "how to do"s are.

The controller is where the user interacts with the application and its models, and the view is what gets displayed to the user. A rule of thumb is if you have to respond to the user's input in some way in the view, then your logic's in the wrong place.

Good view logic:

```
<p><%= @user.name -%> <%= '(admin)' if @user.admin? -%></p>
<ul>
<% @user.documents.each do |document| %>
  <%= render "/documents/#{document.format}_list", :document => document %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

This is bad:

```
<% @user = User.find params[:id] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a performance issue. It's a maintenance issue. For example, if you have a logic in view, it is not easy to write a test for the logic in the system. If it is in controller, it's a snap to write a test. If you have lots of logics in view, it will be problem with webform all over again.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just spent some time on my side projects factoring out if statements from my templates in an mvc (or at least aspiring to be mvc) site that I'm working on.

If you want to stick to the strictest meanings of mvc, then there shouldn't be ANY logical constructs in your view.  So even when rendering a set - lets say a list - you should have a foreach loop which (from your controller) has the arguments for a piece of the template, and calls that piece over and over again.  The thing I don't like about having to do this is that it can lead to very inefficient code if you aren't careful about how you aggregate your final, composite view which has all of the pieces of your view.  This is especially true if the template library you're using has a render method b/c if you're doing things this way - you're likely to call "render" over and over again.  Basically, you're likely to end up doing string aggregation as opposed to building your view with a single stream.

So - what I've been doing, is I have template files I've actually been labeling as "controllers".  So, in here, I'll have IF/FOREACH or other logical constructs and calls to the proper subtemplates/subviews.  I don't think anyone has said that your template file MUST be JUST A VIEW.  I think the paradigm is that your VIEW must NOT have logical constructs.  Isolating those logical constructs by making template files which are actually controllers as opposed to pieces of your view, should provide a happy medium.

Example (using google closure template library)

Mixing logic and view (not good...but you don't really find out why until you've built a complicated view this way):

```
/**
 *
 * Template description
 *
 * @param paramA description of paramA 
 * @param paramB description of paramB
 * @param paramC description of paramC
 *
 *
 */
{template .myTemplate}
     <div class="{$paramA}">
       {if $paramC}
         <span class="{$paramB}">Some content</span>
       {/if}
     </div>
{/template}
```

Separating logic and view.  Note how the controller template file doesn't add anything to the view.  It just calls another template.

Controller template file:

```
/**
 *
 * Template description
 *
 * @param condition description of condition
 * @param parameters parameters to call subtemplate with
 *
 */
{template .myTemplate}
     {if $condition}
          {call .getTemplForCondition data="$parameters" /}
     {else}
          {call .getTempl data="$parameters" /}
     {/if}
{/template}
```

And then template file...now with no logic in view...

```
/**
 *
 * Template description
 *
 * @param paramA description of paramA 
 * @param paramB description of paramB
 *
 */
{template .getTemplForCondition}
     <div class="{$paramA}">
         <span class="{$paramB}">Some content</span>
     </div>
{/template}

/**
 *
 * Template description
 *
 * @param paramA description of paramA 
 *
 */
{template .myTemplate}
     <div class="{$paramA}"></div>
{/template}
```

Comment: PS - I started working on this site just so I could learn more about MVC (I took a DIY approach as opposed to using an explicit MVC framework).  So if what I'm saying is completely wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't performance, it's separation of concerns.  The controller should contain business logic; For example, the logic used to determine what data to fetch given some user input.

The controller then passes data to the view.  The logic in the view should concern itself only with how to display the data to the user.  Do certain things need to be pluralized? Should certain UI elements be displayed/hidden based on the data returned?  The logic for these things are simple and should be the responsibility of the view.

Based on your question, it seems you have the right idea, so long as the simple logic in your view isn't business logic.

Comment: It is very misleading to suggest that a controller should contain business logic when business logic belongs firmly in the model layer. It's the controller s job to work out what to display on the screen and get data from and to the model and that's it. If that means that there is conditional logic in the controller based on business logic then the controller should ask the model what it should do - e.g. render something if model.can_i_do_this? else render not_allowed_to_do_this

Comment: Perhaps it's subjective, but certainly not misleading.  The model, IMHO, should define the data structures, not the behavior.

Comment: lol! This is not subjective. Business logic really does belong in the model and not in controllers. There are many varied and very good reasons for this - perhaps a reply to a question in another forum might help why this is so http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=44042

Comment: It most certainly is subjective, and I would argue bad practice to put business logic in the model.  Some people believe business logic belongs in a separate layer altogether, but that's a discussion for another day.  You sound like you're advocating a MVVM architecture with business logic in the model.  Perhaps Rails' flavor of MVC is a bit of a misnomer in that regard, I don't know as I've never used rails.  Regardless, I strictly advocate a model that is nothing more than objects with properties.

Comment: this is a Rails question and it is very definitely wrong to put business logic in controllers. I really would like to help you to understand why. I'm going to put a blog about this next week as there are very many experienced and non experienced developers that just don't get it as well as yourself.

Comment: MVC is used all over the place, not just by rails.  Now, being that you must "drink the rails kool-aid" to get the most out of rails, you may be right in this instance.  However, I can't stress strongly enough that the "rails way" is not the only way, and certainly not the best way to implement a pattern that is widely used outside of rails.  Your understanding of MVC appears to be the result of exposure to a very constrained use of MVC implemented by a particular framework, instead of an understanding of the pattern in general.

Comment: Maybe the misunderstanding comes from a lack of OO development design knowledge? In Rails terms the model layer is the middle tier. In whatever language you use the middle tier is where the business logic belongs (Plus the database some times.

Comment: @w.brian let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1966/discussion-between-jamesw-and-w-brian)

Comment: No this is not a whole other discussion models are the middle tier (middle layer) in Rails and it is not subjective. Business logic firmly belongs in the models and rails even provides mechanisms such as validations to help you do this. Please do not tell Rails developers that business logic belongs in controllers. IT DOES NOT!

Comment: This goes right back to Ruby, ActiveRecord is a Ruby class ActionController is not. In a ruby app you don't even have controllers but you do have models. You just don't understand the technologies, which is fair enough, hopefully you have a better understanding now

Comment: Your misunderstanding of the subject has become all the more apparent.  A model, a view, and a controller aren't things inherent to a language, they are conceptual objects in a pattern which can be implemented in a variety of ways.  Rails apparently implements this in a very particular way, one that I happen not to agree with, if what you say is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails terms the model acts as a middle tier in a multi-tier app. Put you logic in the models NOT the controllers or the views. If a view or a controller needs to make a choice over what to display then ask the model if it's ok to do something and implement the function in the model.

```
<% if @model.sais_its_ok %>
  OK Go ahead
<% else %>
  Sorry, Not allowed!
<% end %>
```

The best fit for this scenario is to use view helpers but in controllers it's fine to ask the model.
Indeed controllers ask the model all the time without you even realising it.

They will tell a model to save ther data. The model will run validations and if they fail they will tell the controller that it couldn't do this and the model will even tell the controller why (and the vuiews) in the errors hash.

Please if you com from another language remember that the model is the middle tier, controllers just have the job of passing data between the middle tiere (models and the views. This is what a true MVC architecture is all about.

Reply from @jimworm demonstrates this perfectly in his reply with asking the model if it is an admin?